# The main requirement is to convert react-native-android build to an .aar(Android Archive) Library to reuse in Cordova

Tags: android, sdk, react-native, aar

**Commands used**

To create application :

> "npx react-native init AwesomeProject"

To start metro bundler:

> "cd AwesomeProject" and then

> "npx react-native start"

To run on emulator    :

> "npx react-native run-android"

**P.S** - *Path and Environment Variables are all set.*

**I've surfed through the internet on "generating an .aar from React-Native but found no WORKING solution".**

Comment: Why we use it in Cordova is because of business requirements, as we've planned on migrating the app from KnockoutJs to React Native gradually. So instead of a one time migration we would like to migrate module by module.

Comment: I can't understand why you want to convert an application to aar. But you can follow the standart android documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library You don't have to worry about react-native core itself, since it is only a library. But i don't believe you can run react-native library and source code with cordova. I don't think anyone has tried that yet

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem? What result you are expecting, an what you've got instead?

Comment: To answer why? It's for the code base migration from KnockoutJs to ReactNative.
The link you've mentioned is what I've tried, but it's for pure android applications and in the case of a react native android build, it's not working.
And as you mentioned in the last point , it's true. So just looking out for a better solution, if one exists. 
Thank you :) @UğurEren

Comment: @fdermishin Problem - Converting React native android app to .aar(Android archive)Library.
Expectation - once I obtain the .aar, i would have to integrate it within a Cordova application.

Thank you :)